# Ax 2012 disable row on form

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to disable (Non - Editable or Greyout) a complete Record ( Row ) in a Form by Unchecking a Check BOX in that record. In my code disable all record of the form

```
if(MyTable.ChechBox==NoYes::Yes)
{    
    MyTable_ds.allowedit(false);    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to put your logic in the `active(...)` method of your datasource.

`\System Documentation\Classes\FormDataSource\active`

You can simply put:

> `MyTable_ds.allowedit(MyTable.Checkbox);`

You'll also want to disable multiselect on the grid.

Finally, since actually "checking" the box doesn't commit a `write(...)` (save) of the record, you'll want to handle that in some way...either by putting in the modified method of the checkbox `MyTable_ds.write();` or calling `MyTable_ds.allowedit(MyTable.Checkbox);` again.

What you're doing has a few nuances that you'll have to make small tweaks to get working right...most of them you'll discover as you do it.